# Cross-browser SVG sprite stack solution

Tags: css, iframe, svg, stack, sprite

I'm desperately trying to get an SVG sprite stack to work in all browsers (IE8+). I'm using the awesome https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite to generate the stack and I've read up on the topic quite a bit. As https://betravis.github.io/icon-methods/svg-sprite-sheets.html suggests, the safest solution (in terms of browser support) for now, seems to be this

```
<iframe src='bunnies.svg#carrot-bunny'></iframe>
```

This indeed works fine in all browsers I need to target. However this brings up a new problem: because I'm using an anchor in the iframes src attribute, the browser scrolls to this iframe (which of course is undesired).

I've found a workaround for this: I hide the iframe via CSS (display: none) and change it to "display: block", once I get the windows load event. This workaround gets it done in all browsers except Safari, where the browser will scroll to the iframe whenever the iframe is appearing.

I'm kind of lost now. Do you know a way of preventing this behaviour in Safari? Or should I better follow another approach? How do you get your SVG sprite stacks to work?

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently it's not possible to use SVG stacks while supporting all major browsers at the time of writing. I went with SVG symbols (https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/) for now and will switch to SVG stack once anchors are respected in img tags in Safari.